# Cleaning Reactive Table Filters in Shiny App

Tags: r, filter, shiny, shinyapps

I am working on a shinyapp in R and want to clean it up.

The app is ultimately pulling data in, creating a data frame, and then allows the user to filter the data based on reactive inputs IF they have selected from the pickerInput, otherwise it won't filter on that variable. There are 15 variables to select from and the list will keep growing.

Is there a cleaner way to have reactive optional filters besides an IF statement for each variable?

```
 table <- #SQL query from datasource
 unique_value1_list <- unique(table$value1)
 unique_value2_list <- unique(table$value2)
 unique_value3_list <- unique(table$value3)

 updatedTable <- reactive({

     # Filters table for each variables input
     if (length(input$Value1) < length(unique_value1_list)) {
         table <- dplyr::filter(table , value1 %in% c(input$Value1))
     }
     if (length(input$Value2) < length(unique_value2_list)) {
         table <- dplyr::filter(table , value2 %in% c(input$Value2))
     }
     if (length(input$Value3) < length(unique_value3_list)) {
         table <- dplyr::filter(table , value3 %in% c(input$Value3))
     }

  # Always filters on set date range unless changed in input
  dplyr::filter(table, between(value_date, input$date[1], input$date[2])) 

 })
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Can you give more information about the `table`? You can use `dput(head(table))`and copy the result from the console. Also, what arguments were passed to  `pickerInput`?

Comment: Hi @jpdugo17, I have many different columns in all data formats and it will continue to grow constantly. Here is part of the table:
  gender = c("F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F"), 
  age = c(74, 80, 61, 69, 78, 64), 
  age_in_ind = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
  mbr_seq_nb = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01")

The arguments passed to pickerInput are all needed variables in this format with unique value lists generated from the table:
pickerInput(
inputId = "segment",
label = "Choose a Segment:",
choices = ulst$segment,
selected = ulst$segment,
multiple = TRUE
)

Comment: Per above comment, example of segment: segment = c("GROUP", "OVER 65", 
    "UNDER 65", "OVER 65", "OVER 65", "GROUP")

Comment: Can you provide the code from the UI? From what i've seen, input$Value1 should be the same type as table$Value1 but it's not clear how does segment fit in all of this. Regarding to the code, it is possible to shrink it a lot by using a for loop or a walk function.